# How to Clean Layout of Activity in Android

Tags: android

Is there a simple way to clear the layout of an android activity? I am working on an app that currently spans multiple activities and requires keeping track of variables from the different activities to be used in the final activity of my project. I'm just wondering if it's possible to create everything in one single activity, preform an action, store a variable, and then clear the activity screen and load another layout? It seems much simpler to me than having to keep track of multiple variables across multiple activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure, you can set any content view at any time.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

//now do some stuff

//then

   setContentView(R.layout.someOtherLayout);
```

However, this will quickly become unwieldy (believe me I've tried) as your activity grows and grows and grows to reflect interaction with what would natively be placed in separate Activities.  The better approach is to extend Application and store all your persistant variables in that. Any activity can see the parent Application at any time, and you can count on those variables persisting so long as any Activity is visible.  If you need variables to persist through long sleep cycles you'll want to store those in SharedPreferences, but that's true no matter HOW you choose to organize your presentation.

Answer (score 1):

To change the layout, just call `setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);` like you do in your `onCreate` except with the new layout as the parameter.

Or if it is just a couple other views you could use a `ViewFlipper` and flip between multiple different views. I wouldn't do more than three or so views at a time though because ViewFlipper loads all the views at once and this can get quite expensive.

There is a tradeoff with everything though as far as overhead, so perhaps try to find a balance between these and using multiple Activities. I wouldn't be afraid to use multiple Activities, but to also simplify with the above when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can load all layout in one by the tag named "include", and hide others View/layout then show current one when
switch to another View/Layout. Sure, it is poor performance.